# How to skip Android setup UI by command line CLI after flashing Android AOSP?

Tags: android, adb, android-service, android-source, android-build

How can one skip the Android setup UI by command line CLI (e.g. via adb shell) after flashing a local build of Android AOSP on a physical device? Extra question: how can one automatically sign into a Google account via command line CLI (e.g. via adb shell) after flashing Android AOSP?

Answer (score 4):

For the first part of your question where you want to disable the setup wizard, you can try the following commands and then reboot your device:

```
adb shell settings put secure user_setup_complete 1
adb shell settings put global device_provisioned 1
```